# Function without prototype called with non-compatible type

Tags: c, function, language-lawyer, function-call

I read the Standard N1570 section `6.5.2.2 Function calls` and was confused about the special meaning of the function type that includes prototype. Precisely `6.5.2.2(p6)`

> If the function is defined with a type that does not include a
>   prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion are not
>   compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior
>   is undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> — one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type
>   is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is
>   representable in both types;
>
> — both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a
>   character type or void.

`6.5.2.2(p7)` provides a rule of calling function with prototype:

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does include a prototype, the arguments are implicitly converted, as
>   if by assignment, to the types of the corresponding parameters, taking
>   the type of each parameter to be the unqualified version of its
>   declared type.

Consider the following example:

```
struct test_arg{
    int a;
};

void test_no_prototype(const struct test_arg a){ }

void test_with_prototype(const struct test_arg a);

void test_with_prototype(const struct test_arg a){ }

int main(){
    struct test_arg test = {.a = 42};
    test_no_prototype(test);   //1 UB?
    test_with_prototype(test); //2 Fine?
}
```

I think that 1 is UB because `test_no_prototype` does not include prototype and `test` has non-qualified version of `struct test_arg`, but the argument has type `const struct test_arg` which is non-compatible with `struct test_arg` because of different qualification.

I think that 2 is fine because `test_with_prototype` includes prototype and the simple assignment constraints from `6.5.16.1(p1)` allow assignment of to a variable of qualified struct type from non-qualified version of the same struct.

This seems strange and for now I cannot imagine any reason of why we treat functions with and without prototype differently. Probably I understood the rule incorrectly... If so could you explain what it means?

Comment: A function definition without prototype format would rather be the old, obsolete "K&R style" `void test_no_prototype(a) {}`. This is valid C90 but not valid ISO C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The term *prototype* does not mean a declaration of a function preceding its definition. It means a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters (C 2018 6.2.1 2).

`test_no_prototype` has a prototype because `void test_no_prototype(const struct test_arg a){ }` declares the type of its parameter, `const struct test_arg`.

An example of a declaration without a prototype is `void test_no_prototype();`. It is an old style of declaration that should not be used in new code.

Comment: So `void test_no_prototype()` should rather be declared as `void test_no_prototype(void)`?

Comment: @SomeName: If `test_no_prototype` takes an argument, it should not be declared as `void test_no_prototype(void)`, because that declaration says it takes no arguments. Generally, a function should be declared the same way it is defined, although parameter names can be omitted in a declaration that is not a definition.

Comment: Suppose I want to declare (but not define) a function that takes no parameters and provide a definition in the corresponding C file. Is there any difference between the declarations `void foo();` and `void foo(void);`?

Comment: `6.2.1(p2)` provides a definition of that: _A function prototype is a declaration of a function that declares the types of its parameters._ So as you said _An example of a declaration without a prototype is `void test_no_prototype();`_ functions with no parameters are always without prototype.. Is that correct?

Comment: @SomeName: `void foo(void)` declares a function that takes no parameters. This is a prototype: It is a prototype with no parameters (in terms of mathematical logic, every parameter in it has a declared type—there are no parameters, so that satisfies “every parameter has a type”). `void foo()` is a declaration without a prototype. If a function takes no parameters, you should declare it as with `void foo(void)`. Do not use `void foo()`. That is old syntax you should not use in new code.